# Powershell - Match multiple 5-digit substrings in a string

Tags: regex, powershell

We send sales invoices with a prefix of INV. Some customers pay the invoices without the prefix. I want to add the prefix in that case to have the ERP-system recognise these payments. An example of the date is below.

> :61:2204210421C1339,57NMSCTOPF2510474511//GBBK031SCT TOPF2510474511
> :86:RGT FACT 17133 TANQ BROERS SA/RGT39370 TANQ BROERS SA48 AVENUE
> D'ABCDE  :61:2204270427C4808,37NMSCTOPF2520477320//GBJ6009SCT
> TOPF2520477320  :86:RGT FACT 17274.17442.17546 TANQ BROERS SA/RGT39370
> TANQ BROERS SA48 AVENUE D'ABCDE
> :61:2203290329C5518,16NMSCTOPF2485471711//GBCJ001SCT TOPF2485471711
> :86:RGT FACT.16794 16918 17079 TANQ BROERS SA/RGT39370 TANQ BROERS
> SA48 AVENUE D'ABCDE

I need the output to be:

> :61:2204210421C1339,57NMSCTOPF2510474511//GBBK031SCT TOPF2510474511
> :86:RGT FACT **INV17133** TANQ BROERS SA/RGT39370 TANQ BROERS SA48 AVENUE D'ABCDE
> :61:2204270427C4808,37NMSCTOPF2520477320//GBJ6009SCT
> TOPF2520477320
> :86:RGT FACT **INV17274**.**INV17442**.**INV17546** TANQ BROERS SA/RGT39370 TANQ BROERS SA48 AVENUE D'ABCDE
> :61:2203290329C5518,16NMSCTOPF2485471711//GBCJ001SCT TOPF2485471711
> :86:RGT FACT.**INV16794 INV16918 INV17079** TANQ BROERS SA/RGT39370 TANQ BROERS SA48 AVENUE D'ABCDE

I have made this script but [it only matches the first invoicenumber](https://regex101.com/r/qvEUOE/1). How do I match them all in a group?

```
(:61:[0-9]{1,6}[0-9]{4}C[0-9]+\,[0-9]?[0-9]?)(NMSC.+)(\r?\n:86:RGT FACT.{1})([\d]{5})
```

The payment description will always be similar but not always exactly like this. The order will be like this but I am not sure whether they allways use dots to seperate the invoicenumbers for example.

Comment: You can repeat matching the 5 digits matching either a dot or space in between `(:61:[0-9]{1,6}[0-9]{4}C[0-9]+,[0-9]{0,2})(NMSC.+)(\r?\n:86:RGT FACT[ .])(\d{5}(?:[. ]\d{5})*)` https://regex101.com/r/VKkYI3/1

Comment: Thanks but how do I add INV then to all instances instead of only the first one?

Comment: You could split the values of the last group by either a space or a dot and then prepend `INV` There could be another option using `\G` like `(?:(:61:[0-9]{1,6}[0-9]{4}C[0-9]+,[0-9]{0,2})(NMSC.+)(\r?\n:86:RGT FACT)|\G(?!^))[ .](\d{5})` https://regex101.com/r/wYrxQ3/1

Comment: Does every line start with `:61` and are these lines in real life without newlines in between? The format you used in the question does not make that clear...

Comment: Actually each payment (in the Swift MT940 standard) has two lines starting with :61: (date, amount, debit or credit) and :86: (payment description, bank account, bic/swift code). So the relevant line is actually indeed :86: which always starts with :86: and always runs until :61: (=next payment). 
In real life there can be new lines in between so the bank sometimes cuts the :86: into mutliple lines for some reason but my scripts puts everything on its own line so that each line starts with :61: or :86: or [one of the other MT940 codes which I did not mention here as not relevant].

Comment: This works perfectly but what If would want to ad  TANQ BROERS to the match (which comes after the invoice numbers)? Whatever I do it seems to continously break the match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use the `\G` anchor to get [contiguous matches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/anchors-in-regular-expressions#contiguous-matches-g) for the last 5 digits separated by either a space or dot.

Note that you can omit `{1}` from the pattern, and omit the `.` after FACT as that becomes part of the repeating using `\G`

```
(?:(:61:[0-9]{1,6}[0-9]{4}C[0-9]+,[0-9]{0,2})(NMSC.+)(\r?\n:86:RGT FACT)|\G(?!^))[ .](\d{5})
```

**Explanation**

- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `(:61:[0-9]{1,6}[0-9]{4}C[0-9]+,[0-9]{0,2})(NMSC.+)(\r?\n:86:RGT FACT)` Your initial pattern
  - `|` OR
  - `\G(?!^)` Assert the position at the end of the previous match (not at the start)
- `)` Close the alternation
- `[ .](\d{5})` Match either a space or dot and capture 5 digits

See a [Powershell demo](https://tio.run/##pZFNT8JAEIbv/RUradI2lLKzn90mBtpSiBiLAnKhmBhtoglBghgP2N9et6B8HfXwbmbnSTbPzC7fPvPV@0s@n5el@bpYfqzRJWrXjEBAQAhmBKrEQKlyuUxvRvF4cNslXLcl4wDNZi@KrjEFDdApMgJfBMPeGHVDzUDqN9A4TO9QNBwkwxEahU1NqaISn/WZj8JJkt4nqGOFUdxJDjqySsx87Lv0SEcjKSnBlU5fYKwOOr/oXIdI5oFkjOiTM/FfNUpUlZhz8F0QezXmcyb18NtNxX2MD5vaoxM1D4RUDIFQ4GtNLNWf1Wptw/j51MYqX84fn3Jk2a3ArpynuKFmG3BFsatYEW@Luru7Y5cUjl3N4dUdO1u1ssWxpvOV9ezWxYPjTJE3s7PnDS8cC7mWCSYxKbpKJyazyvIb) and a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wYrxQ3/1).

Example

```
$input = @"
:61:2204210421C1339,57NMSCTOPF2510474511//GBBK031SCT TOPF2510474511
:86:RGT FACT 17133 TANQ BROERS SA/RGT39370 TANQ BROERS SA48 AVENUE D'ABCDE
:61:2204270427C4808,37NMSCTOPF2520477320//GBJ6009SCT TOPF2520477320
:86:RGT FACT 17274.17442.17546 TANQ BROERS SA/RGT39370 TANQ BROERS SA48 AVENUE D'ABCDE
:61:2203290329C5518,16NMSCTOPF2485471711//GBCJ001SCT TOPF2485471711
:86:RGT FACT.16794 16918 17079 TANQ BROERS SA/RGT39370 TANQ BROERS SA48 AVENUE D'ABCDE
"@

$input -replace '(?:(:61:[0-9]{1,6}[0-9]{4}C[0-9]+,[0-9]{0,2})(NMSC.+)(\r?\n:86:RGT FACT)|\G(?!^))[ .](\d{5})' ,'$1$2$3 INV$4'
```

Output

```
:61:2204210421C1339,57NMSCTOPF2510474511//GBBK031SCT TOPF2510474511
:86:RGT FACT INV17133 TANQ BROERS SA/RGT39370 TANQ BROERS SA48 AVENUE D'ABCDE
:61:2204270427C4808,37NMSCTOPF2520477320//GBJ6009SCT TOPF2520477320
:86:RGT FACT INV17274 INV17442 INV17546 TANQ BROERS SA/RGT39370 TANQ BROERS SA48 AVENUE D'ABCDE
:61:2203290329C5518,16NMSCTOPF2485471711//GBCJ001SCT TOPF2485471711
:86:RGT FACT INV16794 INV16918 INV17079 TANQ BROERS SA/RGT39370 TANQ BROERS SA48 AVENUE D'ABCDE
```

Answer (score 0):

[@Thefourthbird gave the answer in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72317733/powershell-match-multiple-5-digit-substrings-in-a-string#comment127760310_72317733), it works perfectly and I used following script to adjust the `MT940` statement and put it to Production:

```
(Get-Content -Path $fileName -Raw) -replace '(?:(:61:[0-9]{1,6}[0-9]{4}C[0-9]+,[0-9]{0,2})(NMSC.+)(\r?\n:86:RGT FACT)|\G(?!^))[ .](\d{5})' ,'$1$2$3 INV$4' | Set-Content  -Path $fileName
```

It takes the `MT940` text file and puts `INV` in front of a 5 digit number if the string starts with `:86:RGT FACT`.